# Android, load mp4 videos in a webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

when I try to load a url that looks like (http://mypage.net/786876.mp4), the we webview keeps loading forever and nothing happens. I tried to load the same url on a browser and it loaded fine.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: you tried the same url on the browser of the device you are testing with?

Comment: I use chrome on Galaxy S2, and yes it works fine on it... but when I tried to load that url on the default browser, it didn't load, it offered the video to be downloaded or to launch the media player to run it.